# Definining a C macro that expands to a variable number of elements

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm writing USB report descriptors, which are a sequence of bytes: a tag byte (in which the lower bits tell how many data bytes follow) followed by 0, 1, 2 or 4 data bytes. e.g. to define the logical ranges of an input:

```
uint8_t report_descriptor[] = {
    ...
    0x15, 0x00,                     //   Logical Minimum (0)
    0x26, 0xFF, 0x03,               //   Logical Maximum (1023)
    ...
};
```

Since `0` fits into one byte, we use tag type `0x15` (Logical Minimum with one data byte). But `1023` requires two bytes, so tag type `0x26` (Logical Maximum with two data bytes).

I had hoped to define some macros to make this more readable (and avoid having to comment every line):

```
uint8_t report_descriptor[] = {
    ...
    LOGICAL_MINIMUM(0),
    LOGICAL_MAXIMUM(1023),
    ...
};
```

However, I've hit a snag: that macro needs to expand to a different number of elements depending on the value. I don't see any easy way to achieve this. I've tried tricks like `value > 255 ? (value & 0xFF, value >> 8) : value`, but it always gets expanded to just one byte.

I think the spec allows to just always use the 4-byte tags, but that would be wasteful, so I'd rather not do that.

Is what I'm after possible with the preprocessor?

Comment: Might not be possible. Maybe consider [gpp](http://www.nothingisreal.com/gpp/) preprocessor

Comment: How many different values may occur? If it is only a handful of values, you could have macros `LOCAL_MAXIMUM_1023` etc and then use concatenation in the macro call `LOGICAL_MAXIMUM(1023)`

Comment: They could be any 32-bit integer.

Comment: For the sake of readability and simplicity, what about a compromise? Use a different macro for each number of bytes: `ENCODE_VALUE_1B(0x00)`, `ENCODE_VALUE_2B(0xACDC)`, `ENCODE_VALUE_3B(0x123456)` and `ENCODE_VALUE_4B(0xDEADBEEF)`.  Especially if the argument is encoded in hex like in these examples, I think that this is reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the C preprocessor is powerful enough to do this in a clean way.  If you are willing to resort to the [M4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/index.html) macro processor, it can be done fairly easily.  M4 should be readily available on the vast majority of GNU/Linux systems and portable implementations should be available for most platforms.

Let's define the M4 macros in a separate file and name it `macros.m4`.

```
define(`EXTRACT_BYTE', `(($1 >> (8 * $2)) & 0xFF)')

dnl You probably don't want to define these as M4 macros but as C preprocessor
dnl macros in your header files.

define(`TAG_1_BYTES', `0x15')
define(`TAG_2_BYTES', `0x26')
define(`TAG_3_BYTES', `0x37')
define(`TAG_4_BYTES', `0x48')

define(`EXPAND_1_BYTES', `TAG_1_BYTES, EXTRACT_BYTE($1, 0)')
define(`EXPAND_2_BYTES', `TAG_2_BYTES, EXTRACT_BYTE($1, 1), EXTRACT_BYTE($1, 0)')
define(`EXPAND_3_BYTES', `TAG_3_BYTES, EXTRACT_BYTE($1, 2), EXTRACT_BYTE($1, 1), EXTRACT_BYTE($1, 0)')
define(`EXPAND_4_BYTES', `TAG_4_BYTES, EXTRACT_BYTE($1, 3), EXTRACT_BYTE($1, 2), EXTRACT_BYTE($1, 1), EXTRACT_BYTE($1, 0)')

define(`ENCODE',
  `ifelse(eval($1 < 256), `1', `EXPAND_1_BYTES($1)',
    `ifelse(eval($1 < 65536), `1', `EXPAND_2_BYTES($1)',
      `ifelse(eval($1 < 16777216), `1', `EXPAND_3_BYTES($1)',
      `EXPAND_4_BYTES($1)')')')')
```

Now, writing your C files is straight forward.  Put the following code in a file `test.c.m4`:

```
include(`macros.m4')

`static unint8_t report_descriptor[] = {'
    ENCODE(50),
    ENCODE(5000),
    ENCODE(500000),
    ENCODE(50000000),
`};'
```

In your `Makefile`, add the following rule

```
test.c: test.c.m4 macros.m4
    ${M4} $< > $@
```

where `M4` is set to the M4 processor (usually `m4`).

If M4 is run on `test.c.m4`, it will – omitting some excess white space – produce the following `test.c` file:

```c
static unint8_t report_descriptor[] = {
  0x15, ((50 >> (8 * 0)) & 0xFF),
  0x26, ((5000 >> (8 * 1)) & 0xFF), ((5000 >> (8 * 0)) & 0xFF),
  0x37, ((500000 >> (8 * 2)) & 0xFF), ((500000 >> (8 * 1)) & 0xFF), ((500000 >> (8 * 0)) & 0xFF),
  0x48, ((50000000 >> (8 * 3)) & 0xFF), ((50000000 >> (8 * 2)) & 0xFF), ((50000000 >> (8 * 1)) & 0xFF), ((50000000 >> (8 * 0)) & 0xFF),
};
```

You'll probably find it more convenient to keep the `test.c.m4` file as minimal as possible and `#include` it in an ordinary C file.

If you don't know M4, you can learn the basics rather quickly.  If already using [GNU Autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/), you might find it convenient to use their [M4sugar](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Programming-in-M4sugar.html) M4 macro library instead of the plain M4 I've used above.

Comment: Interesting. What are the advantages of M4 for this use case versus a short script (Python, Lua, might even be possible in Bash) that generates the code?

Comment: @Rena Honestly, probably none… M4 is popular as it is part of the GNU Auotool chain but if you are more comfortable with other scripting languages, they will do the job equally good.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up using M4 to be able to have a nice syntax (even if the macro definitions themselves are a bit hairy).

Answer (score 2):

There is a dirty hack that will achieve the asked functionality. But being a dirty hack, it's unlikely to improve the readability. But it works. First lets define an include file `helper.h` like this:

```
#if PARAM > 255
0x26, (PARAM & 0xFF), (PARAM >> 8),
#else
0x15, (PARAM),
#endif
```

Then in our main we will do:

```
uint8_t report_descriptor[] = {

        #define PARAM 0
        #include "helper.h"
        #undef PARAM

        #define PARAM 1023
        #include "helper.h"
        #undef PARAM

};
```

To see it is working here is the test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t report_descriptor[] = {

        #define PARAM 0
        #include "helper.h"
        #undef PARAM

        #define PARAM 1023
        #include "helper.h"
        #undef PARAM

};


int main(int argc, char** args) {

    int i;
    for (i=0; i < sizeof(report_descriptor); i++ )
        printf("%x\n", report_descriptor[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
15
0
26
ff
3
```

Comment: I'll give a +1 for showing a clever trick.  But as you've said, it ain't pretty.

Comment: That _is_ pretty clever, but I think not much more readable... (and I guess I can't use another macro to clean it up, since a macro can't output `#define` or `#include`.)

Comment: Unfortunately this is the best I can think of. The only cleanup can be done here is to move the `undef` part into the header file. But again, it was just to demonstrate the technique, which might be useful in other cases.